# Unix socket filename error

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, c++14, unix-socket

This is the first time I am programming with Unix sockets so forgive the stupid errors.  I wrote the following function to create a unix socket.

```
int create_server_unix_socket(const string& socket_path) {

    // STEP 1 : socket()
    int unix_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (unix_socket == -1) {
        throw std::runtime_error {"Error occured in socket() call : "s +
            string(std::strerror(errno))};
    }

    // STEP 2 : bind(), setup the address structures for bind()
    sockaddr_un local_address;
    local_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    std::strcpy(local_address.sun_path, socket_path.c_str());

    // unlink from before
    unlink(socket_path.c_str());

    // STEP 2 : bind()
    size_t length = socket_path.size() + sizeof(local_address.sun_family);
    if (::bind(unix_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&local_address),
                length) == -1) {
        throw std::runtime_error {"Error occured in bind() call : "s +
            string(strerror(errno))};
    }

    // STEP 3 : listen()
    if (listen(unix_socket, 5) == -1) {
        throw std::runtime_error {"Error occured in listen() call : "s +
            string(strerror(errno))};
    }

    return unix_socket;
}
```

But whenever I try and create a socket like so

```
create_server_unix_socket("./unix_socket"s);
```

The file that is created in the current working directory is `unix_socke` instead of `unix_socket` and in fact this happens to any name that I try.  If I try `unix_socket_longer_name`, the file produced is `unix_socket_longer_nam`.  I am running this on a Mac OS X (version 10.11.4).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  Also if you notice something horribly wrong in my code, please let me know!  I wrote this by consulting the man pages and I am not completely sure I did it right.  Thanks!

**NOTE** : I am compiling this with C++14, you would need to import the `std::literals::string_literals` namespace to make this work.  Add `using namespace std::literals::string_literals` to the top of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the man page of [`bind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)

> ```
> int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
>             socklen_t addrlen);
> ```

The third parameter is the `addrlen`

> `addrlen` specifies the size, in bytes, of the address structure pointed to by `addr`.

So, what you should be passing, is `sizeof local_address`. Instead, you passed `length` which is `socket_path.size() + sizeof(local_address.sun_family)`. That size is almost enough, but there is no room for the null terminator and it ignores the possibility that `sockaddr_un` may contain padding.

If you really want to pass a length that matches the path rather than the full size of `local_address`, you could use `offsetof`:

```
length = offsetof(sockaddr_un, sun_path) + socket_path.size() + 1;
```

But I don't see an advantage to it over simply passing `sizeof local_address`.

Comment: I thought that was the problem!  I did it right from the man pages but went back on my decision when I looked here http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html and the author seemed to use the length that I used in the code snippet above!

Comment: @Curious I suspect that code probably depends on platform specific behaviour and may well work in some implementations. Did my suggestion fix the problem?

Comment: Yes it did!  I had another question but I think I will ask that as another question soon.  Thanks!

Comment: @Curious no need to doubt everything the author says :) I'm sure they're a cabable expert. It's easy to overlook structure padding if you don't need to deal with portability.